# Сериализацация объектов в Json

Tags: php

У меня есть базовый класс Base, и два класса которые его расширяют Fork,Message. Так же есть класс Page, в котором содержится массив (в котором будут храниться объекты классов Fork,Message)
Возможно ли настроить сериализацию\десериализацию класса page в json?

```
class Base implements{
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getId(): string
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param string $id
 */
public function setId(string $id): void
{
    $this->id = $id;
}
```

}

```
class Fork extends Base{
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $childrens;

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getChildrens(): string
{
    return $this->childrens;
}

/**
 * @param string $childrens
 */
public function setChildrens(string $childrens): void
{
    $this->childrens = $childrens;
}
}



class Message extends Base{
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $inputValue;

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getInputValue(): string
{
    return $this->inputValue;
}

/**
 * @param string $inputValue
 */
public function setInputValue(string $inputValue): void
{
    $this->inputValue = $inputValue;
}
}





class Page{

/**
 * @var Base[]
 */
private $arr = array();

/**
 * @return Base[]
 */
public function getArr(): array
{
    return $this->arr;
}

/**
 * @param Base[] $arr
 */
public function setArr(array $arr): void
{
    $this->arr = $arr;
}
}
```

Перешел из java, там можно настроить Jackson аннотациями, возможно и в php есть хорошая библиотека для этого дела? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вам нужно смотреть в сторону имплементации [JsonSerializable](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php), либо как вам уже посоветовали используя Symfony. JSON - это формат кодирования данных, а не сериализации.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov у меня вся проблема, как мне ДЕсериализовать Json в объект класса PHP. Допустим в той же java, это делается следующим образом (пункт 2.2. Per-Class Annotations) https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

Comment: Вам уже подсказали как, @Dudoserg. Обычным json_encode/json_decode не сохраняются типы объектов, только данные, так что используйте Symfony Serializer или аналоги.

Answer (score 0):

Есть конечно - воспользуйтесь, например, [компонентом Symfony - Serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)

Comment: Спасибо, но что то не могу разобрать, как настроить чтобы в массиве $arr были объекты класса, у меня получается там лежит массив. https://pastebin.com/JWSqNQe4